# how to sort explicit loaded records with hibernate

Tags: hibernate

hey guys and gals.  i have a system that queries a survey.  when i get the survey i have it set with explicit loading so it pulls the questions and the possible answers for those questions.  so the tree would look like this

```
survey
|_questions
  |_answers
```

so, my problem is i need to sort the questions and answers.  there is an order field on each of those tables but i can't figure out how to put the "order by sortorder" clause in the query that returns the questions and answers

Answer (score 0):

HAHAHAHA, well bit more digging i found it.  order-by= on the set of the mapping file.  how simple.  sorry guys